# City shows 'contact.city' on Summary

Tags: contacts

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a problem that I need to fix - one of my sites doesn't display the City on the Summary and only shows 'contact.city', e.g.

[image]

[image]

It's a multi-site running v5.10.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the 'Address Display Format' is not set properly in your system. Navigate to CiviCRM >> Administrator >> Localization >> Address Settings. Check values in 'Address Display Format' field. The **contact.city** should be inside open and closed curly braces eg **{contact.city}**.

Default value of 'Address Display Format'

```
{contact.address_name}
{contact.street_address}
{contact.supplemental_address_1}
{contact.supplemental_address_2}
{contact.supplemental_address_3}
{contact.city}{, }{contact.state_province}{ }{contact.postal_code}
{contact.country}
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I often remove 'State' from the display because it looks odd to use the 3-letter acronym in the UK, but I'd obviously deleted too many characters....